# Are there any refinements of $\langle \vec x,\vec y\rangle \leq \lVert \vec x\rVert_1\lVert \vec y\rVert_\infty$?

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, holder-inequality, young-inequality

The standard Young's inequality states, for $a,b>0$ and $\nu\in[0,1]$, that

$$
\nu a + (1-\nu)b\geq a^{\nu}b^{1-\nu}.
$$

This has been *refined* in various ways, for example see the [refined Young's inequality](http://files.ele-math.com/articles/jmi-05-47.pdf), which states that

$$
\nu a + (1-\nu)b\geq a^\nu b^{1-\nu}K(b/a,2)^{\min(\nu, 1-\nu)}
$$
where

$$K(t, 2) = \frac{(t+1)^2}{4t}$$

satisfies $K(t,2) = K(t^{-1},2)$, so $K(b/a,2) = K(a/b,2)$, and $K(t, 2)\geq 1$ for all $t>0$, so this inequality is sharper.

These type of arguments can lead to refinements of Holders inequality $\lVert f,g\rVert \leq \lVert f\rVert_p\lVert g\rVert_q$ for $p^{-1}+q^{-1} = 1$ and both $p,q$ *finite*.
I am curious if anything is known about the case one of $p,q = \infty$.

Essentially, I need an upper bound on $\langle \vec x, \vec y\rangle$ in terms of the $\ell_1$ norm of $\vec y$.
I can clearly do this with $\langle \vec x, \vec y\rangle \leq \lVert \vec x\rVert_\infty \lVert \vec y\rVert_1$, but I just learned about the refined Young's inequality (and it just helped me move from a trivial bound to a non-trivial bound elsewhere), so I am curious if there are refined bounds in my setting.